# Multiple JavaScript methods at once using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, lodash

I have data that is in all caps. I want to make the first letter of each word capitalized and the rest of the word lowercase but I cannot seem to do it.

I tried this using lodash

```
{
    Header: 'Security Name',
    accessor: 'securityName',
    minWidth: 70, // minWidth is only used as a limit for resizing
    width: 260, // width is used for both the flex-basis and flex-grow
    maxWidth: 300,
    Cell: e => <div>{_.lowerCase.firstUpper(e.value)} </div>,
  },
```

But it won't work. Any ideas on how to make this possible?

Comment: How are you using that in React? Is it rendering a table?

Comment: I only ask because CSS has `text-transform: capitalize` and you could just add a class to the JSX you're rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The reaosn why your code did not work is because the method is not firstUpper but [**upperFirst**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#upperFirst).
Also, you need to write `_.lowerCase(_.upperFirst(e.value))` instead of `_.lowerCase.upperFirst(e.value)`, because JavaScript methods take parenthesis to initiate.

However, the better solution will be using [capitalized](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#capitalize) directly, which is also provided by lodash .

```js
// Example

_.capitalize('FRED');
// => 'Fred'
```